# Trigger to send a notification email to account owner when any new contact created

Tags: apex, trigger, community, salesforcedx

Getting error on line -- "sendTo.add(acclist.owner.email);"

```
trigger emailOwner on Contact (after insert) {
        list<id> accId = new list<id>();
        
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        
        for(Contact con :trigger.new){
            if(con.AccountId!=null){   list<account> acclist = [Select Owner.Email from Account where Id =:con.AccountId];
                
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                
                List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
         sendTo.add(acclist.owner.email);
          mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                
                mail.setReplyTo('b@gmail.com');
          mail.setSenderDisplayName('Conatct Created');
                
                mail.setSubject('new Contact Created to Account');
          String body = 'Dear';
          body += 'One new contact created.';
          mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        
         
          mails.add(mail);
            }
        }
         Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an alternative into the mix.

Apex is good, but can be used to over engineer a simple business need. In this case, from what I can see is that you are only looking for a "notification" email. Process Builder and an Email Alert using a Text Email Template should do the trick.

[image]
[image]
[image]

PS: Make sure your Email Template is marked as Available For Use.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a field from a List. This isn't allowed. You can only get the value from a single record. Also, please note that your code may fail in large data loads, as you're querying the account per record. In addition, you should use the user's Id, not an email address, to avoid hitting the daily bulk mail limits.

```
trigger emailOwner on Contact (after insert) {
    Map<Id, Id> accountOwnerIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        accountOwnerIds.put(record.AccountId, null);
    }
    for(Account record: [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountOwnerIds.keySet()]) {
        accountOwnerIds.put(record.Id, record.OwnerId);
    }
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        Id emailToId = accountOwnerIds.get(record.AccountId);
        if(emailToId != null) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(emailToId);
            mail.setReplyTo('b@gmail.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Conatct Created');
            mail.setSubject('new Contact Created to Account');
            String body = 'Dear';
            body += 'One new contact created.';
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mails.add(mail);
        }
    }
    if(!mails.isEmpty()) {
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the above code. I'm still getting the error

Comment: Illegal assignment from Id to User

Comment: Variable does not exist: sendTo

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setTreatTargetAsRecipient(Boolean) from the type Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Comment: @Gxdev Mistakes were made. They were actually pretty trivial. I've fixed them. setTreatTargetAsRecipient isn't needed, either (it should have been setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient, but the default is true, so not needed here).